# How to setup a property class to extend on all components on VueJS project?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify on my VueJS project and several components has text in uppercase and I need to set `class="text-none"` property on every component that I want it. So, how I can extend one time this attribute to all components or specifics which?

Some examples when I use the property class.

```
<v-tab class="text-none" key="meetingsListTab">Reuniões</v-tab>

<v-btn @click="onClickBack" text class="text-none grey--text">
<span class="material-icons"> arrow_back </span> Voltar
</v-btn>

<v-btn
@click="onClickDeleteMeeting"
outlined
color="red lighten-1"
class="text-none mr-4">
Deletar reunião
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would emit a global event and make all related components listen for it.

```js
// button function
function deleteHandler() {
  this.$root.$emit('<meeting-id>', {action: 'delete'})
}

// on your-component
{
  props: {
    meetingId: {
      type: String,
      default: 'meeting-id'
    }  
  }
  data: {
    noText: ''
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on(this.meetingId, (payload) => {
      if(payload.action === 'delete') this.setNoTextClass
    }
  }
}
```

in your HTML

```html
<your-component 
  :class="[noText, 'grey--text']" 
  key="meetingsListTab">
Reuniões
</your-component>
```

References:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Was I able to answer your question?